# When theme is changed during running theme does not apply correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-theme

When I change theme to dark or vice versa colors is not apply correctly. If app is rerun colors is changed correctly on app. The problem occur only when theme is changed while app is running. No way on dark mode colors apply correctly and design is not displayed as I designed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp">
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/selected_qr_code_scanner_24"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="uiMode">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
</style>
```

Comment: to apply theme change you should restart activity, because theme is resolved before `super.onCreate` in `onCreate` function

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure themes are immutable, once you set it you would have to restart the containing activity to change it. You don't need to close the app just start a new activity(same one) and finish the existing one.

Comment: I noticed a new problem. Color of dark theme is wrong. In android studio, on design section of xml night theme is ok, but when it is run on device colors are wrong.